# how to handle React axios how to handle net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, axios

It was asked before, but if I follow the solution still in the console there is an uncouth error:-

```
    getExchangeAmount(){
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/excurrency?currency='+this.state.currency+
            '&exCurrency='+this.state.excurrency+'&amount='+this.state.amount 

    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        // success
        this.setState({result: response.data})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // handle this error
        console.log('error: '+error);
    })
}
```

in the console:-

> GET
>   http://localhost:8080/excurrency?currency=EGP&exCurrency=EGP&amount=1
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The above is in red which is an error. how to avoid or catch this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have a very similar issue that is driving me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using a node server so install **cors** package on the server side:

```
npm i cors --save
```

in index.js of server side:

```
const cors= require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

then your code shall work..

if you are not using a node server so try this:

```
    getExchangeAmount(){
  var url = '/excurrency?currency='+this.state.currency+
            '&exCurrency='+this.state.excurrency+'&amount='+this.state.amount 

    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        // success
        this.setState({result: response.data})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // handle this error
        console.log('error: '+error);
    })
}
```

Comment: No still having the same error. Only change app.use(cors()); to App.use(cors()); Otherwise 'app' is not defined. Btw, I added  const cors= require('cors');
App.use(cors()); right after all the imorts at index.js

Answer (score -1):

Try Like this

```
getExchangeAmount(e){
e.preventDefault();
  var url = `/excurrency?currency${this.state.currency}&exCurrency=${this.state.excurrency}&amount=${this.state.amount}`

    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        // success
        this.setState({result: response.data})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // handle this error
        console.log('error: '+error);
    })
}
```

Comment: it even makes it worse. Error:- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
    at App.getExchangeAmount (App.js:36). Btw, I don't pass any argument for  getExchangeAmount

Comment: I pushed to my Github. Here is the total project code. I shared the link to the actual code:- https://github.com/madsum/currencyconverter_back_and_front/blob/master/currency_converter_front/src/App.js

Comment: https://github.com/madsum/currencyconverter_back_and_front/compare/master...iamrraj:patch-1   try it and let me know@masiboo

Comment: in ur Demo.js you are not even catching any exception for axios call. So if server is not running or other error it  shows error:- Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error. The whole point of this question was how to avoid or catch this?